# Android + SQL Server + jTDS

Tags: java, android, sql-server

I'm trying to build an android app with connection to our SQL Server. I have downloaded the jTDS JDBC Driver. I have an jar file and have to copy it to my application's classpath. But where is that? I have copied to my workspace in the project directory where the file ".classpath" is. But it seems not to work.... everytime if I'm at the code where I load the class with

```
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
```

it says:

> The source attachment does not contain the source for the file ClassLoader.class. You can change the source attachment by clicking Change Attachmend Source below"

Any ideas? I'm new to java AND android...

Answer (score 4):

no need of that much of mess. 
 
Simply for Mysql Server Data Access or any live server data access.

**Make Use of Web Services**

Its like prepare a dynamic page that have all the fetched data result from the server. Your android application need to hit that dyanamic page URL and then simply read the content from the streams and use them in your application.

Genrally large amount of data is expressed in xml format which is then parsed from the application See on google about SAXParser

In short its like a web page that will echo your server data after your app hit the url of that web page to read the data.

Comment: it will prevent so much memory headache of your android app.
So much code and drivers and all.. more over just a web page to fetch some data from database and echo it simply . this should not be so tough